# Images Not Displayed Properly

Tags: python, kivy

So I'm using background_normal attribute for these buttons. Images all come out looking horrible.

I've tried different text editors and JPEG's.

```
self.background_normal = "Pictures/JPEG/" + self.card.face + self.card.suit + ".png"
```

[image: What it looks like in Kivy]

[image: Original Images]

Comment: Something odd going on here. Please post a [mcve] (including at least one of your card images).

Comment: Are these images actually mostly transparent?

Comment: I donot think so.